# How to update NaN values in a dataframe with a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to replace NaN values in one column when the adjacent column starts with a string.

```
starts_with ={'65S':'test1','95S':test2,'20S':"test3"}
```

Here is the DF

```
15  65String    NaN
16  95String    NaN
17  20String    NaN
```

I would like it to look like

```
15  65String    test1
16  95String    test2
17  20String    test3
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `findall` find the `key` in `dict` , the just `map` back the `dict`'s value

```
df.c3=df.c2.str.findall('|'.join(starts_with.keys())).str[0].map(starts_with)
df
Out[110]: 
   c1        c2     c3
0  15  65String  test1
1  16  95String  test2
2  17  20String  test3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with `^` for match start of string with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by dictionary:

```
starts_with ={'65S':'test1','95S':'test2','20S':"test3"}

pat = '|'.join(r"^{}".format(x) for x in starts_with)
df['C'] = df['B'].str.extract('(' + pat + ')', expand=False).map(starts_with)
print (df)
    A         B      C
0  15  65String  test1
1  16  95String  test2
2  17  20String  test3
```